# C++ Array of char* copying issue

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am learning about pointer to pointers in C++. We are using an array of `char*` instead of `vector<string>` to learn how this works. I am trying to create an `char*` array of length 3 and copy in the strings from a `const char*` array like so:

```
const char* strings[] = { "Red", "Blue", "pink"};
char* new_array[3];
strcpy(new_array[0], strings[0]);
```

I have included the header `<string.h>` but I still get a segmentation fault.

edit: from what people have told me I need to assign an address to each pointer which makes sense. Is there a way I can assign an address to each one that I can then start to write at? I understand I may be writing over the boundary but if it doesn't crash that is fine because this is just a learning exercise for a different concept.

Comment: Careful! when you do `char *new_array[3]`, what are your 3 `char *` pointers pointing to? Hint: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)

Comment: **Make the problem simpler**.  Can you write the code to copy a *single* constant string, not in an array?  Once you get that right, then try to solve the harder problem.

Answer (score 3):

None of the pointers in your target array are pointing at allocated memory.  You need to allocate memory for the strings before you can then `strcpy()` into them, eg:

```
const char* strings[] = { "Red", "Blue", "pink"};
char* new_array[3];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    new_array[i] = new char[strlen(strings[i])+1];
    strcpy(new_array[i], strings[i]);
}

...

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    delete[] new_array[i];
}
```

Or:

```
const char* strings[] = { "Red", "Blue", "pink"};
char* new_array[3];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    new_array[i] = strdup(strings[i]);
}

...

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    free(new_array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For each of the strings in your array `new_array` you need to allocate memory for the string. Right now each of those 3 pointers is uninitialized, so you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

None of the pointers in `new_array` are assigned any memory - you are writing into some random place in memory (undefined behavior).